# The navigation property was not found on the dependent type in Entity Framework migration

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I fixed all the Primary Keys, gave update-database but I have the following error:

I tried to fix it with establishing the foreign keys, but I have a new error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ID_Model' on type 'Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models.Masini' is not valid. The navigation property 'Modele_masini' was not found on the dependent type 'Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models.Masini'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Masini.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models
{
     public enum Da_Sau_Nu
     {
          Da, Nu
     }

public class Masini
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Masina { get; set; }
    public string Numar_inmatriculare { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Modele_masini")]
    public int ID_Model { get; set; }
    public int An_Fabricatie { get; set; }
    public int ID_proprietar { get; set; }
    public Da_Sau_Nu Disponibilitate { get; set; }
    public Soferi Soferi_masini { get; set; }
    public Ture Ture_masini { get; set; }
    public Modele_masini Masini_modele { get; set; }

    internal static void ForEach(Func<object, object> p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Modele_masini.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models
{
    public class Modele_masini
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID_model { get; set; }
        public string Nume_model { get; set; }
        public string Descriere_Model { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Masini> Masini_modele { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Soferi.cs:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 namespace Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models
 {
     public enum DaSauNu
     {
        Da, Nu
    }
public class Soferi
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_sofer { get; set; }
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data_nasterii { get; set; }
    public string Serie_permis_de_conducere { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data_Expirarii { get; set; } 
    public DaSauNu Angajat_curent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ture> Soferi_ture { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Masini> Soferi_masini { get; set; }

    internal static void ForEach(Func<object, object> p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Ture.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Proiect_masini_firma_taxi.Models
{
     public class Ture
     {
         [Key]
         public int ID_tura { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("Soferi")]
         public int ID_sofer { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("Masini")]
         public int ID_masina { get; set; }
         public DateTime Moment_Start_Tura { get; set; }
         public DateTime Moment_Sfarsit_Tura { get; set; }
         public DateTime Moment_logare { get; set; }
         public DateTime Moment_delogare { get; set; }
         public Ture Ture_Sofer { get; set; }
         public Masini Ture_Masini { get; set; } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it has worked for you or not!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that navigation property name in `[ForeignKey("Modele_masini")]` does not the match navigation property name in `public Modele_masini Masini_modele { get; set; }`.

So update your `Masini` mdoel class follows:

```
public class Masini
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Masina { get; set; }
    public string Numar_inmatriculare { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Masini_modele")]
    public int ID_Model { get; set; }

    public int An_Fabricatie { get; set; }
    public int ID_proprietar { get; set; }
    public Da_Sau_Nu Disponibilitate { get; set; }
    public Soferi Soferi_masini { get; set; }
    public Ture Ture_masini { get; set; }

    public Modele_masini Masini_modele { get; set; }

    internal static void ForEach(Func<object, object> p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You also have same problem in your `Ture` model class. So update this too as follows:

```
public class Ture
{
     [Key]
     public int ID_tura { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Ture_Sofer")]
     public int ID_sofer { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("Ture_Masini")]
     public int ID_masina { get; set; }

     public DateTime Moment_Start_Tura { get; set; }
     public DateTime Moment_Sfarsit_Tura { get; set; }
     public DateTime Moment_logare { get; set; }
     public DateTime Moment_delogare { get; set; }

     public Ture Ture_Sofer { get; set; }
     public Masini Ture_Masini { get; set; } 
}
```

Hope this will solve the problem!